# The dataframe cannot execute the timseries transaction query

Tags: database

`df['debit_percentage'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['amount'] / df.loc[(df['cust_id'] == row['cust_id']) & (df['group_no'] == row['group_no']) & (df['d_or_c'] == 'C'), 'amount'].iloc[0] * 100 if row['d_or_c'] == 'd' else 0, axis=1)`

`df['cumulative_debit_percentage'] = df.groupby(['cust_id', 'group_no'])['debit_percentage'].cumsum()`

`df = df[df['cumulative_debit_percentage'] <= 120]`

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

`debit_df = df[df['d_or_c'] == 'd']`

`debit_df['debit_percentage'] = debit_df.groupby('group_no')['amount'].apply(lambda x: x / x.iloc[0] * 100)`

`debit_df = debit_df.dropna()`
`debit_df['weighted_frequency'] = debit_df['debit_percentage'] * 1 / debit_df.groupby(['group_no', 'transaction_type'])['transaction_type'].transform('count')`
`grouped_df = debit_df.groupby(['group_no', 'transaction_type'])['weighted_frequency'].sum().unstack()`
`ax = grouped_df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)`
`ax.set_axisbelow(True)`
`ax.yaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')`
`ax.set_facecolor('white')`
`plt.xlabel('Group Number')`
`plt.ylabel('Weighted Frequency')`
`plt.title('Group Wise Weighted Frequency of Debit Transaction Types')`
`plt.show()`

the code contains some bugs. The transaction is not correct.This code groups the dataframe by **`group_no`** and applies the **`min`** function to the **`cust_id`** column to find the minimum **`cust_id`** value for each group. It then creates a boolean mask indicating which rows have a **`cust_id`** value equal to the minimum

**`cust_id`** for their **`group_no`** by comparing the **`cust_id`** column to the result of the **`transform`** method applied to the groupby object. Finally, the code filters out all rows that don't match the minimum **`cust_id`** for their **`group_no`** by using the boolean mask as a filter. The resulting dataframe contains only the rows with **`cust_id`** values matching the minimum **`cust_id`** for their **`group_no`**.

his code first converts the **`date`** column to a datetime object, then creates a boolean mask indicating whether each row is a credit or not. It then creates a new boolean mask, **`first_credit_mask`**, which is **`True`** for the first credit row for each customer and **`False`** for all other rows. This is accomplished by grouping the **`is_credit`** mask by the **`cust_id`** column and using the **`idxmin`** method to find the index of the first **`True`** value for each group.